# What machine learning technique can help generate spectrum line profiles?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, regression, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to work with Calcium-K line profiles from the Sun.

Image for reference. Please ignore the labels on the image and note that my profiles are not in image format (more info below).
[image: Calcium-K line profile]

I have over 1500 profiles like these for various latitudes and dates. The profiles are saved as 2D numpy arrays, where each array has two rows: the first row contains the wavelength values, and the second row contains the intensity values. So, plotting against each other, we get the profiles as shown above.

I would like to use an ML model to train latitude and time with line profiles. So, given future date and latitude, the model generates a possible line profile.

I'm stuck with how I can map latitude and time with the line profiles. If I flatten each numpy array and make a list of 1D numpy arrays, ANN, LSTM, and CNN models totally fail and show garbage. Random Forest, XGBoost, and KNN don't fare well either.

What algorithm can I use to solve this? And more importantly, how do I retain line profile info (that is lost if flattened) while training?

Any pointers would help. Thanks!

Edit 1: My line profiles are of the shape (512, 2), where row 1 = wavelength; row 2 = intensity.

Edit 2: Including the architectures of my LSTM network.

```
num_samples = X.shape[0]  # Number of samples/sequences
timesteps = 5  # Length of each sequence
num_features = 4  # Number of input features

num_sequences = num_samples - timesteps + 1

X_reshaped = np.empty((num_sequences, timesteps, num_features))

#Reshape input features for LSTM input shape
for i in range(num_sequences):
    X_reshaped[i] = X[i:i+timesteps]

y_reshaped = y[timesteps-1:]


model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer((5, 4)))
model.add(LSTM(1024,activation='leaky_relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='leaky_relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mape', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mape'])
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on how you exactly did the neural network approach? (The code of either CNN, LSTM, etc.)

Comment: @AmirhosseinRezaei, I have added my LSTM network. Does this help? Thanks.